# Search Filter in React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to `map` through a series of data to be displayed in cards on a page. What I'm trying to do is implement search/filter functionality so that when the user types in "bicep", they only see the cards that contain the word "bicep". Ideally I would like to search the entire card, including the description. No matter what I try, I can't get the search bar to have any effect on the cards. I don't get any error messages, but when I search for anything, none of the cards are filtered out, even if they don't contain the search term.

[Here is the CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/). The search function I'm attempting to use is below:

```
function mySearchFunction() {
  var input, filter, div, dl, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  dl = div.getElementsByTagName("dl");
  for (i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {
    a = dl[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[1];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      dl[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      dl[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Javascript so if there is another function/feature that you would recommend, I'm probably just not aware of it yet, and I'm open to anything, as long as it uses hooks instead of classes, and keep in mind I'm still learning this so I'm trying to take things one step at a time (i.e. I don't know anything about Angular or Vue or other non-React front-end frameworks).

Comment: Can you update your question with the issues that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive that this way for example:

Attach onChange handler on input which set stateHook filter, after every change of state render method is called.

Emojies are rendered with filter(u must handle Case Insensitive Search here etc..) and they are mapped to ur object.

Here is code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emoji-site-plzzl?file=/src/components/App.jsx:303-917)

```
function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>emojipedia</span>
      </h1>

      <input
        type="text"
        id="myInput"
        onChange={e => setFilter(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search for names.."
      />

      <div id="myDiv">
        <dl className="dictionary">
          {emojipedia
            .filter(emoji => {
              return (
                emoji.name.includes(filter) || emoji.meaning.includes(filter)
              );
            })
            .map(createEntry)}
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works, except something appears to be wrong with the "||" condition in the filter... it's only searching on the emoji.meaning and ignoring the emoji.name (if I search for "folded", it returns no results.... I will debug at a later date. Thanks for the help, kind sir.

Comment: Fixed by adding .toLowerCase() to variable in the filter and onChange

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes in the code to work .

1. You need to add the state in the component and make use of useState .
2. I added the onChange eventHandler to handle the input change.
3. Rewritten the filter method to filter the data based on the name property. You can make it generic by passing the property on what you want to filter the data.
4. Binded the state variable **emojis** , in the JSX , so that it re-renders the component when you change the state.

Here is the working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/emoji-site-nc81j?file=/src/components/App.jsx

See the code below

```
function App() {
  const [emojis, setEmojis] = useState(emojipedia);

  function mySearchFunction(event) {
    var tempData = emojipedia.slice();
    tempData = tempData.filter(
      data => data.name.indexOf(event.target.value) > -1
    );
    setEmojis(tempData);
  }

  function createEntry(emojiTerm) {
    return (
      <Entry
        key={emojiTerm.id}
        emoji={emojiTerm.emoji}
        name={emojiTerm.name}
        description={emojiTerm.meaning}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>emojipedia</span>
      </h1>

      <input
        type="text"
        id="myInput"
        onChange={mySearchFunction}
        placeholder="Search for names.."
      />

      <div id="myDiv">
        <dl className="dictionary">{emojis.map(createEntry)}</dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Entry from "./Entry";
import emojipedia from "../emojipedia";

function App() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([])

  function mySearchFunction(value) {
    const results = emojipedia.filter(emoji => emoji.name.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    setResults(results)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>emojipedia</span>
      </h1>

      <input
        type="text"
        id="myInput"
        onChange={e => mySearchFunction(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search for names.."
      />

      <div id="myDiv">
        <dl className="dictionary">
        {
          results.length === 0 ? 'no results' : results.map(result => {
            return <Entry key={result.id}
                          emoji={result.emoji}
                          name={result.name}
                          description={result.meaning} />
                        })
          }
          </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```